# android view camera on screen and record while on scree

Tags: android, camera, record

I want to make a simple application that views the users camera on the screen and when they click a button i want the video to record. can this all be done while on the app.

Need help getting started (new to android)

Comment: this line doesn't make sense please clarify:"can this all be done while on the app."

Comment: can the camera be viewed and recorded on the application screen without going to the built in camera app

Answer (score 0):

you should look at the android documentation for [Camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) paying special attention to `MediaRecorder`  and `permissions`